# Assigning subranges of vectors in different processes

Tags: vhdl

I would like to control different sub-ranges of vectors from different processes.

```
type t_regs is array (integer range <>) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
...
signal regs    : t_regs(NUM_REGS-1 downto 0);
...

process (clk, nreset)
begin
    for i in 0 to NUM_REGS-1 loop
        if (nreset = '0') then
            regs(i)(15) <= '1';
        elsif falling_edge(clk) then
            -- set regs(i)(15)   
       end if;
    end loop;
end process;

process (clk, nreset)
begin
    for i in 0 to NUM_REGS-1 loop
        if (nreset = '0') then
            regs(i)(14 downto 10) <= (others => '0');
        elsif falling_edge(clk) then
            -- set regs(i)(14 downto 10)   
       end if;
    end loop;
end process;

-- Set other bits of regs
...
```

Even though the sub-ranges of the vectors being set in each process do not overlap, when simulating this code the values of regs are undefined. I would have expected each bit of the register to be treated as an independent flip-flop.

Comment: Longest static prefix. The loop parameters I are dynamically elaborated. Use static values for indexing values of type t_regs. There's a driver for every element or subelement of a composite signal assigned in a process. Dynamic indexes imply all the possible elements of regs here. The drivers would resolve to 'U' or 'X' if there values are in conflict. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Note both processes encompass every index value for `regs` - `for I in 0 to NUM_REGS-1 loop`. You have two complete sets of drivers in any event.

Comment: While both processes assign to each regs (in the first dimension), the first process assigns only to bit 15 of each reg (in the second dimension), while the second process assigns only to bits 14 downto 10. Thus, there should be no multiple drivers. I believe this to be a simulator error, with the simulator seeing the same signal name in multiple processes and not discerning that only non-overlapping sub-fields are being assigned. At any rate, I reworked my code such that each sub-field is its own signal.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.2 Drivers "Every signal assignment statement in a process statement defines a set of drivers for certain scalar signals. There is a single driver for a given scalar signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one signal assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment statement denotes S or denotes a composite signal of which S is a subelement. ..."

Comment: Did you expand the bus? The full value is undefined because of (9 downto 0), but the other bits should be set correctly!

Comment: I did expand the bus, every bit shows undefined.